# Jira plugin [Workflow transition field validator]

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

We have a unique requirement in jira, where we need to know what all fields are mandatory at the time of state transition. 
i.e, if comment/duedate is mandatory at the time of create we need that information in rest. I came across rest plugin tutorials on atlassian page and able to create helloworld rest plugin for jira.

But how to know using java, that what all field are mandatory during workflow transition.

Workflow validation has been done using Jira Suite Util plugin.

Any help regarding this will be really appreciated.

Thanks, 
Gaurav